# Warning - BlackBerry 9900 Simulator ----Could not erase C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\components\simulator\9900.bug

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Can anybody please explain and give solution to me ?
for the problem occuring while running a project on `Blackberry Simulator 7`....
I have a pop-up

```
Warning - BlackBerry 9900 Simulator
```

`Could not erase... C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\components\simulator\9900.bug`

Thanking you!

-Preetam.

Comment: clean your simulator and try

Comment: preetam, the image is used is mine. So please remove it.

Comment: dont copy others profile picture

Comment: its a copyrighted image, so please remove.

Comment: signare, what happen?  image is nice one....do u have any problem?

Comment: its a copyright image. please remove it.

Comment: Hi,I have a problem, I am unable to add and use "ksoap2-j2me-core-2.1.2.jar"...in my eclipse..can you please send me demo project for "SOAP web service"...(able to add jar and import package but when i use soap object then app not running on simulator,saying " soap jar not found")Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run clean.bat inside simulator folder. You can also try from simulator window File》Reset device

Answer (score 1):

Just Reset or restart ur device simulator and clean simulator from eclipse.